# How Can I Access to Navigation Menu on Existing Activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have 2 Actitivity in my project. There is a NavigationDrawer in MainActivity(my first activity). I can access with hamburger icon the Navigation Menu Items. But I want to access to it in my TrafficActivity. How I can add hamburger icon and access the Navigation Menu Item.

[image: MainActivity]

[image: TrafficActivity]

**my.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.yunus.ototakip.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/beyaz"
    app:subtitleTextColor="@color/beyaz">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

   @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_kullanici) {


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_hatirlatma)
    {

    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_ipucu)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,IpuclariSayfasi.class));
    }


    else if (id == R.id.nav_oyla) {

        }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_cikis)
    {
            //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,GirisActivity.class));
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

}
```

Comment: Create a common Activity class (Say: BaseActivity.java) by extending AppCompactActivity.java. Implement all drawer related stuff into the BaseActivity and extend this class in MainActivity and TrafficActivity.

Comment: Should not I do some stuff in xml files?

Comment: You have to create separate xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it is recomended to use fragment insted of activity:

Move All your MainActivity content **(Contents of the middle, Not DrawerLayout or NavigationView Stuff**) to a fragment named MainFragment(ex):

Add a frameLayout to out content_main.xml :

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
```

And replace it with MainFragment in MainActivity onCreate:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainFragment()).commit();
```

Create another fragment for IpuclariSayfasi activity.

OnNavigationItemSelected() replace MainFragment with IpuclariSayfasi fragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    .......

    else if (id == R.id.nav_ipucu)
    {
      FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
      fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new IpuclariSayfasi(), "IpuclariSayfasi").commit();        
    }

    .......

}
```

This is the standard system for using Navigation Drawer Activity.

Comment: but I'm using BottomBarNavigation in MainActivity. And I'm using FrameLayout for that. Do you think it's okay for this situation?

Comment: Yeah no prob. wrap up middle contents with a new framelayout and replace that by a fragment.